# How to DOM target in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So, in JS I'd do something like.

```
var subItems = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");
```

Then target by "dropItem[0]" or a forEach loop. Now I'm also trying to do this in jQuery. By doing something like:

```js
$("p").click(function() {
  var dropwDown = $(this).find(".dropdown-contain");
  $(dropDown).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-dropdown">
  <div class="whisky">
    <p>Whisky</p>
    <div class="dropdown-contain">
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wine">
    <p>Wine</p>
    <div class="dropdown-contain">
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="beer">
    <p>Beer</p>
    <div class="dropdown-contain">
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cocktail">
    <p>Cocktail</p>
    <div class="dropdown-contain">
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, that doesn't work. This is the HTML I'm trying to target. Then especially the dropdown class.

Comment: There's nothing inside **p**, so the find() will not find anything

Comment: Yeah, already fixed that. Doesn't really do anything though. Still doesn't show it.

Comment: @DarioSanchezMartinez - *"Yeah, already fixed that."* Not in the question you haven't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

- The `.dropdown-contain` elements aren't within the `p` elements, so `find` won't find them. If you go up to the `div` first, it will:

  ```
  $(this).parent().find(".dropdown-contain");
  ```
- `dropDown` is already a jQuery object, no need to do `$(dropDown)` again.
- Nothing in what you've shown hides those `ul`s, so calling `show` on them won't have any visible effect.

Here's an updated snippet using the code above, with `.dropdown-contain { display: none; }` in the CSS so we can see `show` working:

```js
$("p").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".dropdown-contain").show();
});
```

```css
.dropdown-contain {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-dropdown">
  <div class="whisky">
    <p>Whisky</p>
    <div class="dropdown-contain">
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wine">
    <p>Wine</p>
    <div class="dropdown-contain">
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="beer">
    <p>Beer</p>
    <div class="dropdown-contain">
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cocktail">
    <p>Cocktail</p>
    <div class="dropdown-contain">
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: A there, it works now indeed! Thanks. I find the JS nodelist more intuitive.